# Finding the number of bases for $ \mathbb{F}_3^2 $ and isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-fields, vector-space-isomorphism

Find the number of bases for $ \mathbb{F}_3^2 $ and also the amount of Isomorphisms $ \mathbb{F}_3^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_3^2 $

Here if $(v1,v2)$ is a basis, then
$(v2, v1)$ is a different basis.

I have no idea how to approach this question. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be useful to think of the non-singular 2 x 2 matrices. the first column can be any of $3^2-1$ vectors. the second column can then be any of $3^2-3$ vectors. this result may obviously be generalized giving the result that $GL(2,F_{p^n})$ consists of:
$$
\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} (p^n-p^j)
$$
non-singular transformations

Comment: I figured the matrix containing the field $ \mathbb{F}^2_3 $ could be represented as $ row 1 = (x,y,z) $ and $ row 2 = (a,b,c) $ where a,b,c,x,y,z $\in \mathbb{F} $. This would give $3^3 $ possibilities for both $ row 1 $ and $ row 2 $. So I am a bit confused. I think I'm completely off track. Could you simplify it for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your question suggested you are thinking of a degree-2 extension of $F_3$. if you want the result for a degree-3 extension of $F_2$ then the same analysis gives $(2^3-1)(2^3-2)(2^3-4) =168$ non-singular matrices. basically the first row can be any vector except zero. the second must rule out a 1-d subspace, the third a 2-d subspace &C. if you can define carefully what puzzles you, i will attempt a further explanation